# Issue when trying to load image via .load

Tags: jquery, load, imagemap

I have an html page below with a section called #fullInfo. What i'm trying to do is have it so that when a user clicks a area of an image map, it will pull in some data into the #fullInfo div.

I was trying to follow this tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/.

The problem that i'm having though is that when you click an area of the image map, it just takes you directly to the url rather than loading it in the #fullInfo div.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Here's my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
<style>

#content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #c7c7c7;
    border: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main {
    width: 484px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#info {

}
#load {  
    display: none;  
    position: absolute;  
    rightright: 10px;  
    top: 10px;  
    background-color: red;  
    width: 43px;  
    height: 11px;  
    text-indent: -9999em;  
}  

</style>
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('area').click(function() {

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log('toLoad = '+toLoad);
        $('#fullInfo').hide('fast', loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#main').append('<span id="load">Loading...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

        function loadContent() {
            $('#fullInfo').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent());
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#fullInfo').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }
        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }

        return false;   // used so the link does take you to a new page
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">

        <div id="main">
            <!-- <img src=floorPlan.jpg /> -->
            <div style="text-align:center; width:484px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <img id="Image-Maps_4201110211433362" src="http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/4201110211433362_floorPlan.jpg" usemap="#Image-Maps_4201110211433362" border="0" width="484" height="480" alt="" />
                <map id="_Image-Maps_4201110211433362" name="Image-Maps_4201110211433362">
                    <area shape="rect" id="1" coords="68,35,139,85" href="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/mary_blair-2011-hp.jpg" alt="Meeting Room 200" title="Meeting Room 200" />

                </map>

                <!-- Image map text links - Start - If you do not wish to have text links under your image map, you can move or delete this DIV -->
                <div style="text-align:center; font-size:12px; font-family:verdana; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:484px;">
                    <a style="text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" title="Meeting Room 200">Meeting Room 200</a>
                |   
                </div>
                <!-- Image map text links - End - -->

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">

            <div id="fullInfo">

                <img src="floorPlan.jpg" />

                <div id="info">
                    <h3>Some text here</h3>
                    <p>This is a paragraph about something or other here</p>

                    <p><a href="http://google.com title=Google">This here our link text</a></p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post large bits of example code like this. It's a little easier to read and test. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascrtip">
$('area').click(function() {
```

change to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('area').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: It's still taking me to the actual page rather than bringing it in after I change that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P573q/4/ There seem to be other issues but it's not navigating to that link. Check javascript errors. Maybe the script is not running at all because of `text/javascrtip` (typo)

Comment: I actually changed that text/javascript a second ago and it still didn't work.

Comment: It works in the fiddle. Not sure what else to say. Are you getting javascript errors?

Comment: Ok now I see that i'm getting `$ is not defined`.

Comment: You also appear to have wierd double-quotes on your jquery include: `src=”http`  change them to regular double quotes

Comment: Those double quotes are what caused it. I copied the jquery link from a website and it must have had those curly quotes on it. Thanks guys.